# my recording is in slow-motion and the video do not have a lenght (00:00). how to solve it?

Tags: c#, accord.net

I'm trying to record video from webcam with the sound but this is another story, but if anyone had the solution for it I would be grateful.
Code below

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Accord.Video;
using Accord.Video.DirectShow;
using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;

namespace camrecord
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        FilterInfoCollection capturedevices;
        VideoCaptureDevice Videosource;
        Bitmap video;
        private SaveFileDialog saveAvi;
        private VideoFileWriter FileWriter = new VideoFileWriter();
        int w = 640;
        int h = 420;

        private void StartCameras()
        {
            // create first video source
            Videosource = new VideoCaptureDevice(capturedevices[0].MonikerString);
            Videosource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
            Videosource.Start();
        }

        private void video_NewFrame(object sender, Accord.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {

                video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                pictureBox1.Image = video;

        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            try
            {
                // enumerate video devices
                capturedevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

                if (capturedevices.Count == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                for (int i = 1, n = capturedevices.Count; i <= n; i++)
                {
                    string cameraName = i + " : " + capturedevices[i - 1].Name;
                    camera1Combo.Items.Add(cameraName);
                }

                camera1Combo.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            catch
            {
                startButton.Enabled = false;
                camera1Combo.Items.Add("No cameras found");
                camera1Combo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                camera1Combo.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            StopCameras();
        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartCameras();     
            startButton.Enabled = false;
            stopButton.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StopCameras();
            startButton.Enabled = true;
            stopButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void StopCameras()
        {
            Videosource.SignalToStop();
        }

        private void RecordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            saveAvi = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveAvi.Filter = "Avi Files (*.avi)|*.avi";
            if (saveAvi.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                FileWriter.Open(saveAvi.FileName, w, h, 25, VideoCodec.MPEG4, 5000000);
            FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);

        }


    }
}
```

there is no error but when i change the Framerate uper than 30 the picturebox stuck a the last image taken by the webcam and there appear an error in the line of "pictureBox1.Image = video;" saying that the picturebox is used by something else.

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine, and you have two cardinals sins of it in yoru code. You catch to wide and do not let it go on. There are two articles on exception handling that I link a lot and should get oyu up to speed what (not) to do: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: i found the solution but now i have another problem after the button record click the form1 is no longer usable i can not click on any button..